# Transformer Design and Ripple Formula

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, electromagnetism, flyback

When I was researching flyback inductor I saw a formula which is showing the effective transformer core volume with related the ripple factor. r = 2Iac/Idc = ΔI/Idc
[image]

Where does this formula come from?

Comment: Where did you see the formula?